# Visual Studio keeps asking to install Git command prompt tools

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, git-commit

Im using `Visual Studio 2015` and using Git as my code repo. In `Team Explorer` it is asking to `Install 3rd-party Git command prompt tools`, i have restarted `VS2015` and restarted my machine and this message still appears under Team Explorer. What i have also noticed is that  when i make changes to any fill and try to `commit`. I look under `Included Changes` and the only file that is mentioned is a `.suo` file , even though i had been making changes to a `.cs` file.

Update 1:
What i have also noticed  when i go to the file directory and look for a file that i have modified the modified date is not update after i save it.

Comment: To resolve this pop up, go to git-scm.com and install the windows version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can install the `3rd-party Git command prompt tools` within the VS Team Explorer.

You can also download the win version to install : https://git-scm.com/download/win

For the changed files can not be identified issue, make sure you have the correct permission to edit/save the files, also check that if you have created the `.gitignore` file to prevent tracking of specific files. See [Use gitignore to prevent tracking of files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/ignore-files?tabs=visual-studio#use-gitignore-to-prevent-tracking-of-files) for details.

[image]